# Whether or not $C_1(e^{-x}+e^{2x})$ is a general solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Whether or not $C_1(e^{-x}+e^{2x})$ is a general solution for differential equation
$$y''-y'-2y=0$$
Tried since $$r^2-r-2=0$$ has the solution $$r=-1 \text{ or } 2$$
So the general solution is $$y=C_1e^{-x}+C_2e^{2x}$$
But this question asked 
whether or not $C_1(e^{-x}+e^{2x})$ is a general solution. The solution said yes.

Comment: @SimpleArt The thing is whether it is "a" but not "all" general solution, that is what I concern...

Comment: Oh, then you just need to show that it is true for all $C$, either by plugging it in or having $C_1=C_2$

Comment: There is some different usage for "_general solution_" in different textbooks. You may need to check the context.

Comment: A general solution contains as many arbitrary constants as the order of differential equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution manual has a typo.

What you have written (i.e. $y=C_1e^{-x}+C_2e^{2x}$) is typically called "the general solution."

Notice that setting $C_1=0$ and $C_2=1$ shows that $y=e^{2x}$ is "a solution" to the given ODE, but there is no value of $C_3$ that when substituted into $y=C_3(e^{-x}+e^{2x})$ gives the solution $y=e^{2x}$.

In the language of abstract linear algebra, the set of all solutions to this ODE forms a 2-dimensional subspace (of the vector space of all $C^2$ functions on $\mathbb{R}$).  You have described the entire 2-dimensional subspace.  The equation $y=C_3(e^{-x}+e^{2x})$ only describes a 1-dimensional subspace of your (larger) subspace.